# Auto attach a file to a specifc email template

Tags: email, vba, automation, microsoft-outlook-2013

Every morning i have to update a file with some data and then send it to people and its getting a bit laborious having to attach the same file over and over again each day.

I have a template with the recipients and the message body but I wanted to know if there is a way to save the file location so even when i update the file the next email to be sent will be the updated file rather than the old one?

(I do believe i can do it with ExtendedOffice add-in but i wanted to try to avoid it if possible)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using:

- [Outlook VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/vba-outlook) script.
- Free Outlook add-in (like [Mail Merge with Attachments](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesMailMerge) developed by my company).
- Commercial software.